# Mipmapping issue with textures rendered on to a flat quad (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I am having what seems to be a mipmapping problem when rendering textures on to a flat quad.  At some camera positions the object looks fine, but then at others it gets very fuzzy.  Unfortunately I don't really have any good leads on this problem but I thought if I posted some pictures other who have experiences other issue might be able to give me some insight.
Normal:

[image]

Zoomed Out:

[image]

Rotated:

[image]

Could anyone give me any clues about what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem was more of a state issue, the GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH was getting set elsewhere (in this case to 512) but it needed to be 32 for this particular texture so this problem was fixed with a simple (glPixelStorei GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH 32).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are providing the correct mipmaps? Because that looks like you provided corrupt texture data as mipmaps.